# Performing minus from parent to child files using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have three files in `test1` folder:

[image]

I have three files in `test2` folder:

[image]

Common between these two folders is `file2`.

I want to subtract common files between these **two folders** and get only unique files from `test1` folder.

My expected output is:

```
file1.txt
file3.txt
```

I tried using:

```
cls
$parent='D:\test1'
$child='D:\test2'
$final = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()


$parentarrays=Get-ChildItem $parent
$childarrays=Get-ChildItem $child

foreach ($p1 in $parentarrays) {
 foreach ($p2 in $childarrays){
   if($p1 -notcontains $p2){
      $final.add($p1)
   }  
 }
 }

 Write-Host $final
```

But I am getting output:

```
file1.txt.txt file1.txt.txt file1.txt.txt file2.txt.txt file2.txt.txt file2.txt.txt file3.txt.txt file3.txt.txt file3.txt.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a list of filenames in folder 2 and do the same for folder1. Use a `Where-Object` clause to filter out any filename that is also in the reference list:

```
$filesInFolder2 = (Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test2' -File).Name
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test1' -File).Name | Where-Object { $filesInFolder2 -notcontains $_ }
```

Output:

```
file1.txt
file3.txt
```

Comment: hi @theo, i tried to change the answer according to the needs: $as=(Get-ChildItem -Path $parent -File -Exclude *.err).Name.Substring(0,$len) | Where-Object { $subparent -notcontains $_ } can you help me is there any mistake here?

Comment: @DikshitKarki  Remove `.Substring(0,$len)` and `-Exclude` only works if you also add switch `-Recurse`